# How to remove double '/' from file path, bash script

Tags: rna-seq, bash

I'm using the following script to detect strandedness of my paired end RNA-seq data.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd ~/Desktop/fastq

for infile in *_1.fastq
do
   base=$(basename ${infile} _1.fastq)

    docker run quay.io/biocontainers/guessmylt:0.2.5--py_0 GUESSmyLT \
    --reads ${infile} ${base}_2.fastq

done
```

But when I run it, it keeps giving the error:

```
Building DAG of jobs... File path //SRR3475890_1.fastq contains double
'/'. This is likely unintended. It can also lead to inconsistent
results of the file-matching approach used by Snakemake. File path
//SRR3475890_2.fastq contains double '/'. This is likely unintended.
It can also lead to inconsistent results of the file-matching approach
used by Snakemake. MissingInputException in line 46 of
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/GUESSmyLT/subsample: Missing
input files for rule subsample_fastq: //SRR3475890_2.fastq
//SRR3475890_1.fastq
```

Why is it appending double '/' to the fastq file's path? Nowhere in my script did I mention any path.

*I apologize for the very vague title, English is not my first language, so I did not know how else to phrase it.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that the current working directory inside the container is `/`. You can see this with:

```
docker run --rm quay.io/biocontainers/guessmylt:0.2.5--py_0 python \
    -c 'import os; print(os.getcwd())'
```

When [GUESSmyLT](https://github.com/NBISweden/GUESSmyLT) tries to get the absolute path of it's arguments (`--reads`, `--reference`, `--output`, etc), it actually appends a trailing slash to the current working directory<sup>[1](https://github.com/NBISweden/GUESSmyLT/blob/v1.0/GUESSmyLT/GUESSmyLT.py#L21)</sup>, hence the double slash in the returned file names.

To pass the files into the container and ensure that the results are available when it exits, you'll need a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems) mount anyway. For example:

```
docker run --rm -v "${PWD}:/working" quay.io/biocontainers/guessmylt:0.2.5--py_0 GUESSmyLT \
    --reads "/working/${base}_1.fastq" "/working/${base}_2.fastq" \
    --reference "/working/reference.fa" \
    --annotation "/working/annotation.gtf" \
    --output "/working"
```

Comment: Ah of course, thanks. The citation to the GitHub Python code is cool.

Comment: Thank you @Steve for taking the time to give such a thorough reply. It works now!